# ftp inbound-channel-adapter throws exception while synchronizing

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, apache-commons

I have a module written on SI which is running for quite sometime without any hiccups.Lately I have seen the below error in the logs repeatedly

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:156)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:693)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2990)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2965)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2623)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.list(FtpSession.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.list(FtpSession.java:38)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:145)
    ... 20 more
```

After restarting the component the error has disappeared but still I'm curious to know the reason and fix it.

From this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/113767-ftp-inbound-adapter-throws-problem-occurred-while-synchronizing-remote-to-local-dir) I could relate that there might have been some network issue for a while after which I have started getting this error while synchronizing  but the exception should have been stopped once the network connection was restored (if any network issue was there at all).

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using passive ftp (google search for the difference between active and passive ftp).

Active FTP is notoriously difficult with respect to firewalls etc, because the server opens a connection back to the client. This is timing out in your stack trace above. Perhaps some ports are open others are not.

With passive mode, the client initiates the data connection.

Set the connection factory's `clientMode` property to

```
FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE
```

(`2`).